# PHP mail with domain in body

Tags: apache-2.2, php, email, centos6

Running the following code snippet does not work.  The email is never received.  Note that I am using dummy values for email and domain.

```
$to = "email@domain.com";
$subject = 'Mail Test';
$headers = '';
$message .= 'domain123.com';
$sent_message = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

But when I replace domain123.com with anything else that does not contain this text, the email works.

My maillog is empty and I have PHP display_errors turned on.  Seems like there is a filter somewhere that is killing the email if it has this domain in the body.  I am not having this issue with other websites on this same server.  The domain is not blacklisted anywhere that I can see.

I am running PHP 5.4 with Apache 2.2.15 on a Linode with CentOS 6.5.

Comment: What is the result of this test (add it after your code): `if($sent_message){echo('OK');}else{echo('ERROR');}`

Comment: It returns successful.

Comment: So if php display "OK" that mean your mail has been sent. Check if you don't have something which can block mail on your mail server (anti spam for example).

Comment: My understanding is that an OK only means that it was accepted for delivery.  I checked spam and it's not there.  But like I said, if I, for example, remove the "m" from "com", the mail is delivered and received.

Comment: After some tests, i can't reproduce your bug. Maybe you can remove the . from .= to prevent php notice, and remove $headers from mail function as you don't set headers.

Comment: Thanks Froggiz.  No luck here with your suggestion.  I'm still digging.

Answer (score -1):

Forgot to post an answer to this.  The issue was that IPV6 is enabled by default and I did not have IPV6 SPF records setup.  Per what I read, I could either setup the appropriate SPF records or disable IPV6 in exim.  I chose the latter.  I did that by adding the following line to /etc/exim/exim.conf and restarting exim.

```
disable_ipv6=true
```